# Passing arguments to URL object

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Using the URL object in kivy, https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html, if I wanted to change the on_success function to take in another parameter, how would I pass the value to it?

```
def generate_images(sensor_id):
    req = UrlRequest(URL, on_success=url_success)
```

And then in the on_success having something like this

```
def url_success(req, result, sensor_id):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `functools.partial()`:

```
from functools import partial

# ...

def generate_images(sensor_id):
    req = UrlRequest(URL, on_success=partial(url_success, sensor_id))

# ...

def url_success(sensor_id, req, result):
    print(sensor_id, req, result)
```

Another solution is to use a `lambda` functions:

```
def generate_images(sensor_id):
    req = UrlRequest(URL, on_success= lambda req, result, sensor_id=sensor_id : url_success(req, result, sensor_id))
```